# Destroy Session Not Working

Tags: php, session

Hi i creating `session` and want to destroy it after 1 minute if user do nothing  according to the code it should have to show message which i am printing after one minute but it is showing nothing don't know why?

Here is my code

```
  session_start();
$_SESSIONlogin_user = 'abc';
$_SESSION['USER']['login_email'] = 'abc@example.com';
$_SESSION['USER']['login_phone'] = '9876543210';



 if (isset($_SESSION['USER']['login_email'])) {

    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (1 * 60);


     $now = time();
     if ($now > $_SESSION['expire']) {

            session_destroy();
             header('Location: dev.ludhianalive.com');
            echo "Your session has expired! <a href='#myModal'>Login here</a>";
            exit;
        }


 }
```

Comment: is your condition is working? `if ($now > $_SESSION['expire']) {`

Comment: `var_dump($now > $_SESSION['expire']);` check

Comment: ok wait i am checking

Comment: `bool(false)` this is what it showing

Comment: it means your condition is not working, its not session_destroy issue.

Comment: So what the condition should be because i am not that much good in core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting the expiry time to 1 minute on the future in every request **before** checking whether the expiry time is in the past. As a result the expiry time is always in the future.

You should reorder the check for expiry and the code which sets the expiry time.

Additionally, `session_destroy()` doesn't remove the user's data as you expect. There is a full example of deleting a session to log a user out in the [documentation for session_destroy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) which I have included.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login_user'] = 'abc';
$_SESSION['USER']['login_email'] = 'abc@example.com';
$_SESSION['USER']['login_phone'] = '9876543210';

if (isset($_SESSION['USER']['login_email'])) {
    $now = time();
    if (isset($_SESSION['expire']) && $now > $_SESSION['expire']) {
        // Unset all of the session variables.
        $_SESSION = array();

        // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
        // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
        if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
            $params = session_get_cookie_params();
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
                $params["path"], $params["domain"],
                $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
            );
        }

        // Finally, destroy the session.
        session_destroy();

        header('Location: dev.ludhianalive.com');
        echo "Your session has expired! <a href='#myModal'>Login here</a>";
        exit;
    }
    $_SESSION['start'] = $now;
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (1 * 60);
}
```

Comment: Matt, it would be a good idea to check `$_SESSION['expire']` exists (isset) before attempting to test its contents or the first time through this code it will generate an error

Comment: But it expired the session immediately and i want to destroy it after one minute if user do nothing till 1 minute.

Comment: So this code will set the expiry time to 1 minute in the future every time the code is executed. That way, if the user "does something", the expiry time is updated. You were already doing this, but you were doing it **before** checking if the expiry time had been reached.

Comment: I'm assuming that this code appears in every request and the initial four lines are placeholder code that will be replaced with your login logic?

Comment: Yes i have pasted your code and it is working fine thanks for you help :)

Comment: Can you please tell me why are using `$params = session_get_cookie_params();
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
                $params["path"], $params["domain"],
                $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]` code there?

Comment: That section is copied verbatim from [the example in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). It's removing the existing session cookie for the user.